# Bash to match two variables for time difference

Tags: bash, sed, awk, mysql

I have a `bash` command fetching user account details from the MySQL using command

```
select creationdate from users;
```

which gives me the following result

```
Name     Account Creation Date   Mobile 
User1    2015-06-18 16:00:00     29292922
User2    2015-06-18 16:06:00     56896906
User2    2015-06-18 16:08:00     16842146
```

Now what I want is to match each user `ACCOUNT`, `CREATION`, `DATE` with the current date time, and if its creation date is under 5 minutes then it should list the accounts like

```
New accounts are user2 and user3
```

Something like that. So that I can send SMS to them that their accounts are registered now.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to get for results?

Comment: show the sql that the script is running, seems like you want to modify the sql statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update this thread. Found the solution same day by using following

```
mysql -u$SQLUSER -p$SQLPASS -e "use $DB; select creationdate,login,package,expirydate,mobile from users WHERE creationdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE;"
```

Answer (score 3):

`mysql` should be able to do that for you. But if you have to post-process that output, I'd use:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -lne '
  if (/^(\S+)\s+(\d{4}\S+\s+\S+)/ and
      $t = Time::Piece->strptime($2, "%Y-%m-%d %T") and
      time - $t->epoch <= 5*60
     ) {print $1}'
```

That assumes user names can't contain spacing characters.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas this is mysql command i am trying to run to get the creation time from radius database in mysql. how can I sue mysql syntax to show accounts which account creation time is under 5 minutes? (so that I can schedule a script which run after each minute or 5 mnts and get the new accounts list) 
MYSQL command
`select creationdate from users;`

Comment: maybe this will work ?
`select creationdate from users WHERE creationdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE;`
??

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk, you'd do

```
awk '
    { time = $2 " " $3; gsub(/[-:]/, " ", time); t = mktime(time) }
    (systime() - t) <= 300 {print $1}
'
```